# Redirects in `next.config.js` while using `@next/bundle-analyzer`?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have the following code in my `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
    experimental: {
        modern: true,
    },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
     ...
    }
})
```

I want to redirect from `/` to `/about` page.

The Next.js documentation says that this is how you should use [redirects](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#redirects):

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I use `redirects` in my case, i.e, while using `@next/bundle-analyzer`?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve, what did you try, and what did you get?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov done. sorry I just copy-pasted the question from the Next.js forum where I could omit a lot of stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  experimental: {
    modern: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    ...
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or more clear:

```js
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  experimental: {
    modern: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    ...
  },
  redirects: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```